# PDI 9.2 how to use variable containing dynamic list of values in Table Input SQL, in the WHERE IN clause

Tags: kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have created steps to populate a variable with a dynamic, comma delimited list of values. I have added single quotes to the values. How to I use this variable in my Table Input step?

The variable is being set properly:
`Set variable V_npi_list to value ['12345678910', '1528361342', '1952633216', 'NOTNULLBPNPI', 'NOTNULLBPNPIDIFF1', 'NOTNULLBPNPIDIFF2', 'NOTNULLBPNPIDIFF3', 'NOTNULLBPNPIDIFF4', 'NOTNULLBPNPIDIFF5', 'NOTNULLBPNPIDIFF6', 'TESTATTNPI', 'TESTATTNPIDIFF1', 'TESTATTNPIDIFF2', 'TESTATTNPIDIFF4', 'TESTATTNPIDIFF5', 'TESTATTNPIDIFF6', 'TESTREFNPI', 'TESTREFNPIDIFF2', 'TESTREFNPIDIFF3', 'TESTREFNPIDIFF4', 'TESTREFNPIDIFF5', 'TESTREFNPIDIFF6', 'TESTRENDNPI', 'UNKNOWN', 'distinct_npi']`

What is the syntax for using this variable in the Table Input step? What I have now is not working, and adding single quotes around the variable like you would for a single value does not work either. Any advice/guidance is greatly appreciated.
[Table Input step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHYeJ.png)

I would like the logic to be:
`SELECT taxonomy_code FROM schema_name.npi_taxonomy WHERE npi in ('12345678910', '1528361342', '1952633216', 'NOTNULLBPNPI', 'NOTNULLBPNPIDIFF1', 'NOTNULLBPNPIDIFF2', 'NOTNULLBPNPIDIFF3', 'NOTNULLBPNPIDIFF4', 'NOTNULLBPNPIDIFF5', 'NOTNULLBPNPIDIFF6', 'TESTATTNPI', 'TESTATTNPIDIFF1', 'TESTATTNPIDIFF2', 'TESTATTNPIDIFF4', 'TESTATTNPIDIFF5', 'TESTATTNPIDIFF6', 'TESTREFNPI', 'TESTREFNPIDIFF2', 'TESTREFNPIDIFF3', 'TESTREFNPIDIFF4', 'TESTREFNPIDIFF5', 'TESTREFNPIDIFF6', 'TESTRENDNPI', 'UNKNOWN', 'distinct_npi');`

Comment: A variable in Pentaho is a string, so your list is being interpreted as a single string. Instead of using variables, I would use something else to store the list of values and passing it to the table input step. Maybe a temporary table with a join in your input step, so you don't need to pass the list of values?

Comment: @AnaGH Thank you for your response! Unfortunately, the Table Input step is querying a Redshift cluster/database that I'm unable to write to. Unless you're suggesting another way to use a "temp table" that I'm not thinking about, I'm hoping there is another way to use a dynamically created list of values to use to query the table.

Comment: OK, I was wrong, you can pass a list of values in a parameter, I have just checked in a Oracle DB and it works, so it seems like something fishy specific to Redshift or your parameter hasn't the value you are expecting. If you check with just one parameter and something equivalent to this Oracle query in Redshift: SELECT test_column FROM (SELECT 'TEXT1' test_column FROM DUAL UNION SELECT 'TEXT2' test_column FROM DUAL) test_table WHERE test_column IN (${P_TEST}), does it works? You fill up the default value of P_TEST as 'TEXT1','TEXT2'